# How to fix incorrect aspect ratio in video files

Tags: video, video-conversion

I have a number of video files of various formats (mostly MP4 and FLV) that have apparently been encoded with the wrong aspect ratio, so when they are played with standard settings they appear stretched. If I select the correct aspect ratio manually in the player they look fine, but it is annoying to do that every time. Is there a tool to fix this in the file itself, preferably from the command line and without reencoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into ffmpeg which is the swiss knife of video encoding and metadata editing on linux.

You may be interested in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/907933/correct-aspect-ratio-without-re-encoding-video-file)

The abstract of the best answer is to try that :

```
ffmpeg -i <INPUT_FILE> -aspect 720:540 -c copy [OUTPUT_FILE]
```

Comment: Regrettably, this doesn't seem to have any effect. `ffmpeg` reports that it changed the DAR, but playing the output file with VLC shows exactly the same stretched appearance as playing the original file.

Comment: Can you send me a file that has the problem ? It may be the file as it may be the default configuration of VLC ?

Comment: @Tilman have you tried something new recently ?

Comment: My tests point to VLC's hardware acceleration as the culprit. If I set the "Hardware-accelerated decoding" option to "Disable" the video appears correctly. `mplayer` on Linux and VLC on Windows 10 both play the same file correctly out of the box. Looks like the Linux VLC hardware acceleration ignores the SAR value in the metadata and plays all videos with square pixels (unless manually configured otherwise). -- I'm marking your answer as correct for my original question as this is obviously a separate problem.